# Help with Testing Database.Batchable

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

I have a class with the following:

```
global with sharing class MS_Batch_Delete implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    
    global final List<MS__c> mss;
    
    global MS_Batch_Delete( List<MS__c> ms ){
        this.mss = ms;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
        
        for(MS__c m : mss){
            ids.add( m.Id );
        }
        
        return Database.getQueryLocator( [SELECT Id FROM MS__c WHERE Id IN :ids] );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> msScope){
        delete msScope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

I have a test class with the following:

```
@isTest
public class MS_Batch_Delete_Tst {
public static testmethod void testMSBatchDelete(){
        // Create a project with mss
        MS_Project__c         project = MS_Test_Utility.sampleProject('My Test Project'); 
        List<MS__c> mList   = new List<MS__c>();
        
        insert project;
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            mList.add( MS_Test_Utility.sampleMS(project.Id, null, 'My Test MS ' + i) );
        }
        
        Test.StartTest();
        Database.executeBatch( new MS_Batch_Delete(mList) );
        Test.StopTest();

        // Test records were deleted
        Integer msCount = [SELECT count() FROM MS__c WHERE Project__c = :project.Id];
         
        System.assertEquals( 0, msCount );
    }
}
```

The test class covers the code at 80%. It doesn't cover the section:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> msScope){
    delete msScope;
}
```

I am still very raw at Batchable stuff. Can anyone point me to how I can cover this?

Answer (score 0):

Ug. I forgot to insert mList. After doing the insertion it covered 100%.